# Is it a bad idea to keep scripts in /root?

Tags: linux, bash, root, bash-script

Is it a bad idea to keep scripts in /root? Simple bash scripts that have the following permissions:

-rw-r--r--

They execute fine when ran as root, but is this bad practice? It's a multi-user system, that needs sudo to execute the scripts in question when not logged in as root....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one answer to your question as you can put them anywhere you like. It's a matter of taste and (aesthetic) opinion which do not boil down to one single correct answer.

I'd probably put them somewhere under `/usr/local`. For scripts meant to be run only by the superuser, I'd probably put them in `/usr/local/sbin`. For scripts meant to be used regular users of your system, I'd put them in `/usr/local/bin`.

From a historical perspective `/usr/local` still sounds like a good place to put things which are, eh, "local".

Comment: Would the permissions need to be changed if I were to put them in /usr/local? I take it they would if a user other than root would want to execute them?

Comment: Proper permissions for executable scripts have the executable bit set, so 0755 sounds appropriate in this case. See also the answer for where to put things for superuser and where to put things for the rest of the bunch.